# As a Sorcerer of the Efreeti Bloodline, can I turn Stone Call into Fire Call?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, sorcerer

I'm playing a Sorcerer with the [Efreeti Bloodline](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/efreeti-bloodline). That means that I can change the elements in my spells to Fire using this feature:

> Bloodline Arcana: Whenever you cast a spell that deals energy damage, you can change the type of damage to fire. This  also  changes  the  spell’s  descriptors  to  match  this energy type

So my question is, can I turn Stone Call into Fire Call?

If so, where can I find the Fire spell’s descriptors?

Answer (score 12):

Stone Call is not able to be changed by this ability. Stone Call deals Bludgeoning damage, not energy damage.

If it was eligible, the descriptor changed would be the [earth] portion of the School line of the spell (found [here](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advanced/spells/stoneCall.html#_stone-call)).

Comment: This is correct; "stone" (or bludgeoning) is not an energy type, and thus not subjected to the Bloodline ability.